# Selenium select folder windows dialog

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtc83.gif)

There are many examples on what to do with file upload, however I could not find anything in selecting folder. Any ideas how to handle this ?

**UPDATE:**

I have tried 3 different ways but none worked :

- the first is using sendkeys(). This does not work because there is no input field. This dialog opens when you click a button.
- The second is using AutoIt, which is used in the uploading files dialog. It causes an error when i use it because I am not uploading a file but just selecting a folder.
- the third is robot, where I copy the path I want to the clipboard and try to paste it with robot. It did not work for me.

**Update 2:**

If you open chrome://extensions/ on chrome browser and tick developer mode you will see a load unpacked extensions buttons. This is the button that when you click you get this windows dialog:[image]

Comment: While posting question Please add sufficient details in your question which helps other to understand the motive

Comment: @mosaad Can you consider updating us with the AutoIT case when you see `error when i use it because I am not uploading a file but just selecting a folder`. Thanks

Comment: Can you show the html for the whole div containing the button? I've encountered a website where in the button tag was containing the input field itself. e.g something like <button>your label<input display="none" id="hiddenInputField"/></button>.In this case you can directly use sendKeys()

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways by which you can handle File Upload :

**Way 1:**

```
WebElement fileInput = driver.findElement(By.name("uploadfile"));
fileInput.sendKeys("C:/path/to/file.jpg");
```

**Way 2:**

By using Robot Class API:

```
driver.findElement(By.By.name("uploadfile")).click();
Robot r = new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_KP_DOWN);        
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_KP_DOWN);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_KP_RIGHT);       
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_KP_RIGHT);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Hope it will help you

Answer (score -1):

Selenium support is for Web browser and not for windows dialogs.
the only option for you is to write automation using coded UI or Autoit.

Answer (score -1):

Selenium only works on Web browser, You can use AutoIT but I see you already tried it. In that case I would suggest you to use Sikuli.